# Using DateInterval to add weeks to a DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

Currently my code is adding a week, but I'm using Days instead of Weeks. I've read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.y) and don't quite understand how it works.

[`PHP: DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.y)

```
# Adds 7 days to the project launch date.
$project_launch_date->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
```

Instead of adding manual 7 days, how can I specify, 'add a week', or 'add n weeks'?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If DateInterval is unclear for you, you can use more clear **modify** of DateTime class.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+1 day');
$date->modify('+5 week');
```

I prefer to use modify, because it makes code more readable without comments

In case you prefer to use DateInterval, here is good reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

So 5 weeks will be P5W, 3 month will be P3M, 5 weeks AND 3 month P3M5W and so on.

Comment: Does `modify` change the DateTime of the calling object inline? Or do I need to go: `$date = $date->modify('+1 day');`

Comment: Yes, it changes original object (as well as adding DateInterval). If you need to preserve it you can use clone: `$modDate = clone $date; $modDate->modify('+5 week');`

Comment: From the documentation on that method, it looks like it's dangerous to add or subtract months from a date. Have you noticed this as well?